# Not able to run the RoR project using rails s. Could not find pg-0.17.1 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

I am trying to run a ruby project. After I am in the project directory, I am doing `rails s` .

It gives me this error: **Could not find pg-0.17.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.**

On doing `bundle install` , I am getting this

**An error occurred while installing pg (0.17.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.17.1'` succeeds before bundling.**

So when I am running sudo `gem install pg -v '0.17.1'`

Getting this :

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
```

So I am not sure what's really missing here, I am running ubuntu 13.10. Please help!

Comment: almost the same issue. Thanks mate.

Comment: almost the same? It's identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says "Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header"

Try installing `libpq-dev`

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Comment: But a couple of days ago I was able to run the project, Although I will install this and check.

Comment: It worked. I didn't try to install libpq-dev earlier because I Was able to run the projects couple of days earlier so I wonder how come it asks to install all of sudden.
Anyways, Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you done any package update lately?

Comment: Yes, I do the apt-get update almost daily.
That could be the case.